# Retain notes on an imported row after source update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add comments and highlight rows imported by IMPORTXML or IMPORTHTML. The problem is that the source data often changes, with new rows added. When a new row is added, the notes and highlighting on my sheet no longer correspond to the original row.

Unfortunately I can't provide the exact example as my source is private, but [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NgJaBfEke3VtVR9h94XP0GmTWQifaw3mR5IBufYusds/edit?usp=sharing) shows what I'd like.

Comment: _Sheet 2 is the main 'master sheet'. This sheet displays values from the import sheet in a user-friendly manner._ Without knowing the layout of the spreadsheets, one doesn't know what information is included on Sheet2, and how. Please share your spreadsheets.

Comment: I've changed me question to avoid confusion between 2 sheets. The idea is the same, i'm trying to retain notes and formatting from an imported source.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a change to the workflow.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117735/how-to-keep-cells-paired-with-query-results

1st Sheet is the import sheet.

2nd Sheet contains a column with your references to import sheet. The key here is to write an apps script that looks for differences between the two sheets and adds any missing references to main. Then, you have fully modifiable rows in main that reference import.